# Merge different array of objects with one same property and same length

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I have three arrays of the same type, each of the same length, and I need to merge them into one based on the property they share.
Example:

classes:

```
public class X
{
    public DateTime Epoch { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
};

Public class Body 
{
    public X[] Weight {get; set;}
    public X[] Height {get; set;}
    public X[] ShoeSize {get; set;}
};
```

all these array have the same length and the property "Epoch" is the same for each element and in the same order (so `Weight[0].Epoch == Height[0].Epoch == ShoeSize[0].Epoch` ... `Weight[1].Epoch == Height[1].Epoch` and so on)
I need to have an array of objects with the merged properties, like so:

```
resultArray[n] = {
    Epoch: Weight[n]/Height[n]/ShoeSize[n].Epoch
    Height: Height[n].Value
    Weight: Weight[n].Value
    ShoeSize: ShoeSize[n].Value
}
```

How can I achieve this? I've been trying with a `Dictionary` to iterate over the arrays but I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is that's what you meant? Cause I struggled to unsterstand it properly.

```
 var results =
            from height in body.Height
            from weight in body.Weight
            from shoeSize in body.ShoeSize
            select new
            {
                Epoch = height.Epoch,
                Height = height.Value,
                Weight = weight.Value,
                ShoeSize = shoeSize.Value
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ `Zip` function to join arrays together by index:

```cs
var result = Body.Weight
    .Zip(Body.Height, (w, h) => (w, h))
    .Zip(Body.ShoeSize, (wh, s) =>
        (weight: wh.w,
         height: wh.h,
         shoeSize: s,
         epoch: wh.w/wh.h/s.Epoch))
    .ToArray();
```